# Invalid status code : 0 in node.js API

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, postgresql-9.4, pg-promise

I am building a simple api in node and express with postgre as Db following a tutorial.I am still learning and new to this tech.I followed everything as said and gave full permission to postgre thinking about issue with my db.But when i check it with postman i am getting this error Invalid Status Code : 0

my server.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var api = require('./api/index');

var app = express();


///////////////////////
// Server Middleware
///////////////////////

app.use(logger(app.get("env") === "production" ? "combined" : "dev"));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// CORS
// This allows client applications from other domains use the API Server
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});


//////////////////
// API Queries
//////////////////

app.use('/', api);


//////////////////
// Server Setup
//////////////////

app.set("env", process.env.NODE_ENV || "development");
app.set("host", process.env.HOST || "0.0.0.0");
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.listen(app.get("port"), function () {
    console.log('\n' + '**********************************');
    console.log('REST API listening on port ' + app.get("port"));
    console.log('**********************************' + '\n');
});


////////////////////
// Error Handlers
////////////////////

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status( err.code || 500 )
        .json({
            status: 'error',
            message: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500)
    .json({
        status: 'error',
        message: err.message
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

queries.js

```js
var promise = require('bluebird');

var options ={
    promiseLib : promise
};

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
var connectionString = 'postgres://localhost:5432/star';
console.log(connectionString);
var db = pgp(connectionString);


function getAllStarships(req, res, next) {
  db.any('SELECT * FROM starships')
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          data: data,
          message: 'Retrieved all starships'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}


module.exports ={getAllStarships: getAllStarships,};
```

index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(200)
      .json({
        status: 'success',
        message: 'Live long and prosper!'
      });
});



var db = require('./queries');

router.get('/api/starships', db.getAllStarships);


module.exports = router;
```

Querying Db is working fine from the pgadmin editor and returning the table.

Sample DB

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS startrek;
```

CREATE DATABASE startrek;

\c startrek;

CREATE TABLE starships (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  registry VARCHAR,
  affiliation VARCHAR,
  launched INTEGER,
  class VARCHAR,
  captain VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO starships (name, registry, affiliation, launched, class, captain)
  VALUES ('USS Enterprise', 'NCC-1701', 'United Federation of Planets Starfleet', 2258, 'Constitution', 'James T. Kirk');

Any Help Appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this..Problem was with Authentication.Modified my query.js with

```js
var db = pgp({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'star',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'pes'
});
```

And it worked.

Comment: From your config, you connection string was supposed to be: `var connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:pes@localhost:5432/star';`. See the [Connection String Syntax](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Connection-Syntax#connection-string).